# Broadcast Receiver ACTION_SEND does not show up

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

i want to use a broadcast receiver for "implicit intents" who use the type ACTION_SEND.

It's still very basic but anyway my app/receiver already does not show up, no matter which app's "share menu" i try.

excerpt from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".SaveReceiver" >
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="YourDrive" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="YourDrive" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I've tried setting a mimeType, but nothing helps. Do I have to set a specific mimeType or can i just check it later on (via Java code when handling the content)? What am I doing wrong, so that my app doesn't show up in "Share menus" of all apps...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to use a broadcast receiver for "implicit intents" who use the type ACTION_SEND.

`ACTION_SEND` is an activity action, not a broadcast action. You cannot pick up `startActivity()` calls with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

> What am I doing wrong, so that my app doesn't show up in "Share menus" of all apps...

You are not implementing an activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: Hmm, this sucks, I think... It seriously limits the amount of usecases. You don't always want to start an activity when sharing something.

Comment: @PaulPraet: "You don't always want to start an activity when sharing something" -- the vast majority of "sharing" scenarios in use today involves the user providing additional information about the sharing operation. Things like the recipient's address, or the folder, or the tags, or whatever, based on what the application doing the sending needs. That being said, you are welcome to create a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity that handles the sharing action.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I will have to but I consider this a hack/workaround. Even if most applications will indeed use activities, I just don't understand why Android prohibits to do it in another way..

Comment: @PaulPraet: The `Intent` message bus operates three separate channels, so `startActivity()` for `ACTION_SEND` (the documented pattern) cannot trigger a service or a `BroadcastReceiver`. Implicit `Intent` actions do not work with services (there is no way for the user to choose something) or broadcasts (all receivers receive the broadcast). You are welcome to design your own, more flexible "sharing" system, one that perhaps wraps around the current one, and convince the world's Android developers to support yours.