# Obtain every shared text between any apps in android

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

How can I obtain every single text that is shared via ACTION_SEND intent in android, between any two applications?
I plan on making an app which can store every shared link from any application.

Comment: fortunately you cannot do that

Comment: That is not possible for an ordinary Android app. *Maybe* on a rooted device you could do something, perhaps via an Xposed modules.

Comment: To capture the event as per your need, you need to register a broadcast receiver. Implementation is beyond the scope of this answer. Fortunately(from security perspective), ACTION_SEND does not broadcast an event, rather it is related to an activity. You can find a matching issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12901763/7724205